# I have forgotten what sites I have used my gmail account to login in to

Tags: account-management, google-account

Is their any way to find out what websites I joined w/google login?

Answer (score 1):

Go here: https://security.google.com/settings/security (or access this page from your account settings at [google.com/settings/account](https://www.google.com/settings/account))

At the bottom of the page, under "Connected applications and sites" click on "Review Permissions"

The following page will show you all of the apps and sites that have been granted access (either app-specific access or quick sign-in through Gmail credentials, which is what you're looking for)

Clicking on "Revoke Access" will remove the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

1. bring-up a Google service like Gmail.
2. login
3. Goto https://www.google.com/settings/account
4. In the left side menu click account/dashboard
5. click on Authorize Account access

You should see every 3rd party account that uses Google for access.